# how to install gazebo on linux mint 17

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi

I want to ask about how to install gazebo on linux mint. I know that it's similar with Ubuntu, but I don't know how to make installation script work on my distro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8482/how-to-install-gazebo-on-linux-mint-17/) by [user](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1159/user/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the answer, need only to apply the following change on the first step on this tutorial [Step-by-step Install](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install#Step-by-stepInstall)

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list'

by

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list'

---

Originally posted by [user](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1159/user/) with karma: 11 on 2015-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1